Why is the behavior of my checkbox different on a mobile device than on a desktop PC?
I have a Blazor Wasm app that works as expected on a desktop PC but acts "strange" on a mobile device. I created a Blazor fiddle, here.
Just click the checkboxes. You will see, they act like radio buttons. That's what I want. Now,

enter the dev tools
emulate a mobile device (CTRL + Shift + M)
activate checkbox "one"
move the "cursor" not exactly to the vertical center of "one" but a little lower. Stay within "one"
click again and see, that "one" is deselected and "two" is selected
Do not move the cursor, click again at the exact same position and see that now "one" is selected
click, click, click... at the exact same position toggles between "one" and "two"

What am I doing wrong? Am I even doing anything wrong? I mean, it works as expected on a desktop PC.
Edit
This is reproducible with plain HTML. Please see [here][2] (sorry, link does not work on edit. jsfiddle.net/Lrvp53gm). Just enter the dev tools, emulate a mobile device, click on the disabled "one" and see, that "two" is selected.

First time in my life i see blazor, but this popped in my front page. Html wise i think nesting the input in a label is screwing you. Cause it makes the whole thing clickable. If you replace it with a div for example checkbox triggers only when clicking directly on checkbox. just my two cents..

I want the whole thing to be clickable. To be honest, it makes me insane, when on a website, I have to click the checkbox itself.

Yeah tbh what i wrote does not make much sense. Cause the same "issue" still exists but this time only below each checkbox. It prolly has to do with the way touch works in mobile, but i am just guessing so i 'll let someone else answer something helpful

Maybe, it does make sense, what you wrote or is at least an important note, because when I moved the <label ...> underneath the <span>, I do not see this issue.

Please share more details, like the code involved. Is ths reproducable with plain HTML?

Everything necessary is involved in the blazor fiddle. Yes, it is reproducible with plain HTML. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrvp53gm/. Just enter the dev tools, emulate a mobile device, click on the disabled "one" and see, that "two" is selected.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

As is described here, on mobile devices, touch target sizes are automatically increased to 48x48dp if the element sizes are smaller. That's exactly what happens in above example. If a checkbox is not disabled, the target size of the second checkbox is not extended to overlap the first checkbox, but it is extended if the first checkbox is disabled and therefore not clickable.
